# Split uint32 into two uint16

Tags: go, type-conversion, bit-manipulation, uint32, uint16

How does one go about splitting a single uint32 var in Go into two uint16 vars, representing the 16 MSB and 16 LSB respectively?

Here is a representation of what I am trying to do:

```
var number uint32
var a uint16
var b uint16

number = 4206942069
```

Now how would one go about assigning the 16 MSB in `number` into `a` and the 16 LSB into `b` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code to assign the 16 most significant bits in `number` to `a` and the 16 least significant bits to `b`:

```
a, b := uint16(number>>16), uint16(number)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EFTOqOKiwyn).